# RESTful design pattern in Java EE

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am intent to develop a Restful API design in Java EE, but I have faced tow different models of implementation of the Restful services.

the first model uses @EJB in the rest classes to retrieve data:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource 
{   
    @EJB
    UsersFacade em;

    @GET
    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
    @Path("{name}")
    public User getUser( @PathParam("name") String _name ) 
    {
        UsersBean u = em.findByName(_name );

        if ( u == null )
        {
            throw new WebApplicationException( 404 );
        }
        return User.fromEntity( u );
    }

   ....
}
```

and the second one which is produced by NetBeans is like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("entities.customer")
public class CustomerFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Customer> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CustomerDBPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public CustomerFacadeREST() {
        super(Customer.class);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Customer find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    ....
}
```

As you might noticed, the differences here is that in the second method Rest class implementation is SLJB (Stateless Java Bean) and it uses @PersistenceContext to get instance of JPA, and also it extends AbstractFacade.

But in the first methods it only uses @EJB to retrieve instance of Bean.

which one do you prefer? and why?

Comment: This is totally unrelated to REST, your question is about `@EJB` vs `@PersistenceContext`. Please [edit] your question and reduce it to what is necessary to formulate your question.

Comment: @Lutz Horn, I want to know that, which one is better practice to implement Rest based API. and why?

Comment: It does not matter. REST is not about choosing between different ways of wiring dependencies. Both classes are identical in everything that is related to REST:

Comment: @LutzHorn then your last comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter. REST is not about choosing between different ways of wiring dependencies. Both classes are identical in everything that is related to REST.